# The index signature in typescript defines the string type, why does it become the intersection type of string | number when used

Tags: typescript, vue.js, frontend

Here is my code

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
interface NumberDictionary {
  [index: string]: string;
}

const formInfo: NumberDictionary = {
  name: "john",
  want: "eat",
};

Object.entries(formInfo).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  console.log(key, value);
});
</script>
<template>
  <form>
    <input v-for="(value, key) in formInfo" :name="key" :value="value" :key="key" type="text" />
  </form>
</template>
```

- The key in forEach is of type `string`
- The key in the v-for conditional rendering is `string | number` type

[image]

[image]

why is this？

Comment: Terminology: `string | number` is a *union*, not an *intersection*.  Could you [edit] to change that (or do you mind if I do)?

Comment: I can't answer the question, but I can say that the interface is not needed.  You can assign the built in type [Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type), e.g. `Record<string, string>` to the formInfo instead of NumberDictionary. This should still accomplish what you want of a typed object with string keys and string values, and will also avoid the error.

Comment: @yoduh yes，I did solve it with Record...